# QuickSort working on small size vectors but not on large

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have tried writing an implementation of QuickSort but there is some kind of bug with it which I am not able to identify. The code below works well on a vector of small size like 100 but when I try to provide 10,000 numbers from a file, the program does not stop running. Any help would be great.

```
int Partition(vector<int> &nums, int low, int high, unsigned long &numIterations) {
  int paritionIndex = low;
  int paritionElement = nums.at(paritionIndex);
  int potentialPivotIndex = low + 1;
  for (int i = low + 1; i < high; ++i) {
    if (paritionElement > nums.at(i)) {
      std::swap(nums.at(potentialPivotIndex), nums.at(i));
      ++potentialPivotIndex;
    }
  }
  std::swap(nums.at(potentialPivotIndex - 1), nums.at(paritionIndex));
  //++numIterations;
  return potentialPivotIndex - 1;
}

void QuickSort(vector<int> &nums, int low, int high, unsigned long &numIterations) {
  int p;
  if ((high - low) > 0) {
    p = Partition(nums, low, high, numIterations);
    QuickSort(nums, 1, p - 1, numIterations);
    QuickSort(nums, p + 1, high, numIterations);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your partition function is not correct. even the output it generates for smaller size inputs is not correct.
I have changed it based on the code presented [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-for-quicksort/) as follows:

```
int Partition(vector<int> &nums, int low, int high, unsigned long &numIterations) {

    int pivot = nums.at(high);    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (nums.at(j) <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(nums.at(i), nums.at(j));
        }
    }
    swap(nums.at(i + 1), nums.at(high));
    return (i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Roya for helping me fix the code. The approach suggested by you takes the last element as the pivot element and I was trying to take the first element as the pivot element.
I was able to fix my code by changing the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I found two problems with my initial code.

1. In the `QuickSort` function I am supposed to give the variable `low` to the function but I gave it the constant value `1`.
2. I changed the `for loop` of the `Partition` function to the range `high]` and not `high)` and the main function called the `QuickSort` function with `size - 1`

Making the amendments above fixed the code and I was able to sort vectors.